# White smoke from Passat

Tags: engine, vw, passat

My 2000 VW Passat has no power and faint white smoke. Once I turn off the vehicle, the smoke becomes greater for a minute or two.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your question to add as many details as possible. For example, diesel or petroleum engine?  Does the vehicle run at all?  Where do you see the smoke coming out?  Is the car using a lot of oil?  The more information you add, the more likely we will be able to provide helpful suggestions.

Comment: It's coming from underneath center ofvehicle

Comment: that's a good start. Is there anything else you can tell us?

Comment: We need more info in order to corner an answer.. coolant level is ok? White smoke is usually vaporized water: be it condensed on the exhaust and let out through the first minutes of running or even leaked in coolant.

Comment: next, if its coming out of the 'center of the vehicle' (there's no normal exhaust point there), could you look there with a flashlight and narrow it down? Broken exhaust or something else?

Answer (score 0):

White smoke from a diesel is normally an indication that combustion isn't reaching full temperature, but I'm confused that it's coming from the centre of the car,with the engine running is there full flow coming from the tail pipe of the exhaust ?